# Restore the title label format at the end of appendix

Tags: titles, titlesec, appendix

As invoking of `\appendix` will change the `section` number format from `arabic` to `Alpha`, I construct a pair of macros named `\appendixon` and `\appendixoff` whose function is to keep the number format changing within these two macros. Any `section` number will return to its original format after `\appendixoff`. But they don't work as I expect. Though the section number format can be re-defined once more, I don't want to repeat it. Is there any better method?

**PS:**

When the format of `section label` changes into non-arabic number, `Roman` for example, the section labels in appendix also change to Roman number, how to prevent it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\appendixon}[1][]{%
  \bgroup\parindent0em\appendix{\LARGE\bfseries Appendix}
}
\newcommand{\appendixoff}{\egroup}
% Why do `\bgroup` and `egroup` here do not function?

\begin{document}

\section{Pre appendix}
\appendixon
\section{section of appendix}
\appendixoff
\section{Post appendix}%Here, the section title format fails to go back to its original defination.
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\Roman{section}}{1em}{}
\section{Post titleformat}
\subsection{subsection post titleformat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to make another macro to save section numbers, like:

```
\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{savedsection}% for remembering the last chapter number
\preto\appendix{\setcounter{savedsection}{\arabic{section}}}% remembering!
\newcommand\resumechapters{% the \appendix command with some tweaks
  \setcounter{section}{\arabic{savedsection}}% restore chapter number
  \gdef\@chapapp{\sectionname}% reset chapter name
  \gdef\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}% make chapter numbers arabic
}
\makeatother
```

This macro helps you to skip or resume section numbers without restarting.

MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{savedsection}% for remembering the last chapter number
\preto\appendix{\setcounter{savedsection}{\arabic{section}}}% remembering!
\newcommand\resumechapters{% the \appendix command with some tweaks
  \setcounter{section}{\arabic{savedsection}}% restore chapter number
  \gdef\@chapapp{\sectionname}% reset chapter name
  \gdef\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}% make chapter numbers arabic
}
\makeatother

% \let\cleardoublepage\relax% compressed output of MWE

\newcommand{\appendixon}[1][]{%
  \bgroup\parindent0em\appendix{\LARGE\bfseries Appendix}
}
\newcommand{\appendixoff}{\egroup}
% Why do `\bgroup` and `egroup` here do not function?

\begin{document}

\section{Pre appendix}
\section{Pre appendix, section 1}

\appendixon
\section{section of appendix}
\section{section 2 of appendix}
\appendixoff
\resumechapters
\section{Post appendix}

\section{Post appendix, section 2}

\end{document}
```

## Update

To make the section format in Roman add this block:

```
%%%%%
% You need \usepackage{apptools} for this method
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\IfAppendix{\Alph{section}}{\Roman{section}}}{1em}{}
%%%%%
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{apptools}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{savedsection}% for remembering the last chapter number
\preto\appendix{\setcounter{savedsection}{\arabic{section}}}% remembering!
\newcommand\resumechapters{% the \appendix command with some tweaks
  \setcounter{section}{\arabic{savedsection}}% restore chapter number
  \gdef\@chapapp{\sectionname}% reset chapter name
  \gdef\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}% make chapter numbers arabic
}
\makeatother

%%%%%
% You need \usepackage{apptools} for this method
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\IfAppendix{\Alph{section}}{\Roman{section}}}{1em}{}
%%%%% 

% \let\cleardoublepage\relax% compressed output of MWE

\newcommand{\appendixon}[1][]{%
  \bgroup\parindent0em\appendix{\LARGE\bfseries Appendix}
}
\newcommand{\appendixoff}{\egroup}
% Why do `\bgroup` and `egroup` here do not function?

\begin{document}

\section{Pre appendix}
\section{Pre appendix, section 1}

\appendixon
\section{section of appendix}
\section{section 2 of appendix}
\appendixoff
\resumechapters
\section{Post appendix}

\section{Post appendix, section 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When the section tittle format is altered by `\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\Roman{section}}{1em}{}`, the section labels in appendix also turn into `Roman` number.  So, can your solution be made better to think of this? Thank you!

Comment: @Updated answer. Check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myappendix}{\par
  \newcounter{tempsec}%
  \setcounter{tempsec}{\thesection}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}
  %\clearpage % You could add \clearpage here to let the appendix start at new page
  {\parindent0em\LARGE\bfseries Appendix}
  }
  {
  \setcounter{section}{\thetempsec}
  \gdef\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Pre appendix}
\subsection{Pre appendix subsection}
\begin{myappendix}
\section{Section of Appendix}
\subsection{Appendix subsection}
\end{myappendix}
\section{Post appendix}
\subsection{Post appendix subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]